# EditorFor dilemma

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I understand that `Html.EditorFor` is the best practice for creating form fields, but I'm really annoyed that I cannot add html attributes to it.

I understand the reason for that, but I just cannot imagine form fields without css class declarations. Is it really the formal best practice to use `EditorFor`, or should I use `TextBoxFor`, or even plain HTML element, for defining additional html attributes?

In addition, since I'm planning to handle all form elements using client-side scripts, I don't really need any special server-side functionality, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what advantages do I get from using `EditorFor` / `TextBoxFor`.

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use templated helpers for `Html.EditorFor` which really is the only reason to use it in the first place.

here's [an mvc2 article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html), but it's the same in mvc3.

Comment: So if I don't want to start messing with custom template, is there any added value in EditorFor?

Comment: Sure if you don't care about attributes or assign them after :)